# How can I connect this file with a firebase database?

Tags: android, database, firebase

So can you help me to transform it to connect that to a firebase database,
my app create 2 type of data, "the title of the game" and the "description of the game", there are 2 editText, I just want to write these datas to my firebase database. Thanks !

```
package be.wakanda.ideejeux;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class NDb extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String dbname = "MyNotes.db";
public static final String _id = "_id";
public static final String name = "name";
public static final String remark = "remark";
public static final String dates = "dates";
public static final String mynotes = "mynotes";
private HashMap hp;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public NDb(Context context) {
    super(context, dbname, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("create table mynotes"
            + "(_id integer primary key, name text,remark text,dates text)");
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + mynotes);
    onCreate(db);
}

public Cursor fetchAll() {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(mynotes, new String[] { "_id", "name",
            "dates", "remark" }, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
public boolean insertNotes(String name, String dates, String remark) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("dates", dates);
    contentValues.put("remark", remark);
    db.insert(mynotes, null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

public Cursor getData(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor z = db.rawQuery("select * from " + mynotes + " where _id=" + id
            + "", null);
    return z;
}
public int numberOfRows() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, mynotes);
    return numRows;
}
public boolean updateNotes(Integer id, String name, String dates,
                           String remark) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("dates", dates);
    contentValues.put("remark", remark);
    db.update(mynotes, contentValues, "_id = ? ",
            new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
    return true;
}
public Integer deleteNotes(Integer id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(mynotes, "_id = ? ",
            new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
}
public ArrayList getAll() {
    ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + mynotes, null);
    res.moveToFirst();
    while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(remark)));
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(dates)));
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(name)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}}
```

*I have already connected my app with a firebase database so I just need help to connect this file with my firebase database*

Answer (score 0):

Refer firebase docs, here's the link :- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart